# TestNG - set a "global" variable so that certain tests will always fail

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I'm writing Selenium UI tests for my e-commerce company.  We use a test company credit card that (unfortunately) has a credit ceiling.  Occasionally the credit ceiling will be reached during testing, the "user" will be given an Auth denied message, and the test will fail. I want to set a flag somewhere that, when set to true, will result in all tests using the fake credit card will fail automatically.

Here is a basic setup of my code:

**Base.java**

```
public class Base 
{    
    public WebDriver driver = null;     
    public WebDriver getDriver() 
    {
        return new ChromeDriver();
    }    
}
```

**Page.java**

```
public class Page extends Base 
{
    By ccField;
    By successElement;

    public Page(WebDriver driver) 
    {
        this.driver = driver;
        ccField = By.id("ccField");
        successElement = By.id("success");
    }

    public boolean sendCreditCard(String num) 
    {
        driver.findElement(ccField).sendKeys(num);
        return driver.findElement(successElement).isDisplayed();
    }

}
```

**TestBase.java**

```
public class TestBase extends Base 
{    
    @BeforeMethod
    public void setup() 
    {
        Base b = new Base();
        driver = b.getDriver();
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown() 
    {
        driver.quit();
    }   
}
```

**PageTests.java**

```
public class PageTests extends TestBase 
{   
    Page page;
    boolean failedBecauseOfAuth = false;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setup() 
    {
        page = new Page(driver);
    }

    @Test
    public void one() 
    {
        // Single ship (for example)
        boolean success = page.sendCreditCard("5555555555555555");
        Assert.assertTrue(success);
    }

    @Test
    public void two() 
    {
        // Multi ship (for example)
        boolean success = page.sendCreditCard("5555555555555555");
        Assert.assertTrue(success);
    }

}
```

Essentially, if `one` failed because of an auth denied error, I need `two` to automatically fail at the beginning of the test. The problem is, every-time I set a flag (like `authFailed = false` as a field of `PageTests.java`, and then set `authFailed = true` when needed) it gets reset at the beginning of the next test run.

Comment: Well, I don't need it reset.  I need it to stay set.  The problem is that any variable does get reset when i don't want it to.

Comment: One way I can think of is make the other test cases depend (as in TestNG's `dependsOnMethods`) `one()`.  So if `one()` fails the rest won't run. But that does not help if `one()` succeeds and one of the subsequent methods reaches the ceiling and fails.

Comment: Have you tried to work with a file instead of variables? And check/read that file at the beginning of the test and write to it when it fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should separate authentication from other logic thus you could put it to beforeclass method. It will cause both tests to fail.
2. You can make "two" dependent on "one". It will cause "two" to fail. Although it's not very well to do like this, you should know this feature:

   ```
   @Test(dependsOnMethods = { "one" })
   public void two() {...}
   ```
3. Make authFailed static, therefore it will keep the value for every test method.

In my opinion, the preferable  solution is #1, because it separates the logic. Independence is quite important, you know.

Comment: Thanks very much!  I don't know why I simply didn't think to make the variable static.  This works perfectly.  Refactoring might be better, but sometimes simpler is also good!